# submit form using link tag with angularjs

Tags: forms, angularjs

I'm still new with angularJS. I've been trying to make a custom button and attach it to my form instead of using regular button. I've tried couple of approaches and so far none of them worked well. now when I press enter inside the input field I get the "results" view perfectly loaded to the main page. but when I click the search button "a" link tag the view loads then disappears instantly. as well as the location of the browser changes to "results" then goes back to "/#/" only. I have no idea why and what's causing this.

here's my html:

```
<div id="search-container" ng-controller="SearchController">
  <form ng-submit="submitQuery()">
    <div>
      <input id="keywords" name="keywords" ng-model="query.keywords"  placeholder="please enter query" value="" required/><br>
      <a href="#" id="search-btn" ng-click="submitForm()"><img src="/Images/search-icon.png" alt="Search" title="Search" /></a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

here is my model and ngjs controllers:

```
var bfapp = angular.module("blogfinder", []).config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/results', {
    templateUrl: 'PartialViews/results.html',
    controller: 'ResultsController'
  });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

bfapp.controller('ResultsController', function ($scope) {
});

bfapp.controller('SearchController', function ($scope, $location) {
  $scope.query = { keywords: "" };

  //on form submit
  $scope.submitQuery = function () {
    if ($scope.query.keywords !== null) {
      $location.path('/results');
    }
  };

  //on button click
  $scope.submitForm = $scope.submitQuery;
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

well I feel so stupid. I've just found the solution after banging my head for couple of hours. Although this has never been mentioned on any site. All I needed is to remove "#" from `<a href="#" id="search-btn" ng-click="submitForm()">`. Now it works like charm.

Comment: can you also pass form as an argument of your method to check the form validity, display errors etc. ?

Comment: now this works even without removing the # (as tested on angular@1.6.9)